# Meaning of いいように and はからう in a certain context

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension, literature

I am reading the book 鵺の家 by 廣嶋玲子, and I have a question about the usage of the phrases いいように and はからう in the following.

> 兄達に無性に会いたくなった。巣篭りのお役目が無事におわったら、燕堂に里帰りをお願いしてみよう。兄達の休暇が終わるまで、沖野家に戻っていて**いいように**、**はからって**もらおう。楽しい想像に、ようやく気分が高揚してきた。

My translation attempt:

> Akane (the main character, who is adopted by a rich family) wanted to meet her older brothers very much. If her role at the Nesting Ritual were successful she thought that she would ask Endō (the head of the rich family) for a favour (he promised her earlier that she can ask for anything). She would ask that he allow her to stay at the House of Okino (her home) until the end of the holiday of her older brothers. Upon this happy thought, her mood was finally uplifted.

What exactly do these phrases mean in this context. How to analyze them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[はからう](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E8%A8%88%E3%82%89%E3%81%86/#je-60077) means *to see to it*. It is often used with adverbs, without mentioning explicitly what is done (in this sense, it is close to *to manage*).

From the linked entry:

> なんとか計らいましょう
>
> I'll see to it.／I'll take care of it somehow.

It can be used also like *to see to it that ...*, which is the case for the sentence in question.

Literally

> 兄達の休暇が終わるまで、沖野家に戻っていて**いいように、はからってもらおう。**

can be translated to

> I **will have someone see to it that (I) can (/have the permission to) be back** in Okino's house till the end of the vacation of the brothers.

Practically your understanding is correct, but I made the literal translation for はからってもらう.

---

In grammar terms, understanding ように as *so that*
and はからう as *make arrangements* should clarify.